# Hiding files with apache

Tags: apache, security

I've started using SCSS so in my css folder in my project, I have main.css and main.scss.

Is there any way I can prevent hide main.scss when I put this on my ftp? So it's still there, but not available for direct access?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the reason, why you want to do this? If one can access the `main.css` (what they probably must be able to), they will found nothing new in `main.scss` :?

Comment: Because there's no reason for them to be looking at the main.scss file.

Comment: Thats more an argument for me: If theres no reason for the user to look at it, there is no deeper reason for hiding it ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put this inside a .htaccess in the directory with the file you want to hide. Rename the file appropriately though (instead of yourfile.css).

```
<files yourfile.css>
    deny from all
</files>
```

Of course you can also do this in your httpd.conf file aswell but the paths will need to be amended.

Comment: In my AWS lightsail/bitnami image of wordpress I added it here: /opt/bitnami/wordpress/.user.ini

Answer (score 3):

The problem with @GhostInTheSecureShell's answer is that this also denies access to the files, so the browser cannot download `yourfile.css` any more, which is probably not what you wanted.

To hide files (or directories) from index listings, but still allow access to them, use

```
IndexIgnore yourfile.css
```

in your `.htaccess` file.

This also works with patterns, so you can hide all css files using

```
IndexIgnore *.css
```

Or just name the files that you want to hide with a certain pattern, so, for example

```
IndexIgnore hide_me_*
```

will hide all files or directories that start with `hide_me_`.